# Loading huge amount of Product records in React Js axios Get Request

Tags: reactjs

really finding this framework giving lots of features.My question is I am trying to request around 38916(>30000) amount of data in my React application and then showing them in a grid view in React.I am using Axios to load the large datasets coming through API.Could someone tell me how to load huge amount of records in less amount of time in React JS?Also I want to send the request for multiple api parallely.If anyone have any idea or better one Please post soon.

Comment: I believe user can't see 38916 records at the same time. It would be better if you can fetch the data on demand like pagination/lazy load etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:

- Pagination/lazy load. If it includes images too then lazy load images too [lazy load images with react](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/lazy-loading-images-in-react-for-better-performance-5df73654ea05)
- Use virtualised list to render all data at once
  [virtualised list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized)

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer,Pagination is already there in my app.Lazy loading is a good option for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you had to get all products in once , you should show to user with pagination or lazy load, for example 10 item every page and if user want's more data change pagination number..